# Oracle SQLDeveloper: How to get a condensed list of Unique values based on YEAR range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that consists of 4 columns: NAME, STARTYEAR, ENDYEAR, IDNUM

How do I get a distinct list where the STARTYEAR is the MIN year for that distinct NAME and IDNUM and the ENDYEAR is the MAX year for the distinct NAME and IDNUM.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE ZZ_YEARRANGE (
NAME varchar(10),
STARTYEAR varchar(5),
ENDYEAR varchar(5),
IDNUM varchar(10));

INSERT ALL
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Derick','1995','1998','ABC-100')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Derick','1999','2005','ABC-100')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Derick','1998','2003','ABC-101')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Rick','2001','2010','DEF-200')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Rick','2007','2015','DEF-200')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Rick','2002','2008','DEF-201')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Chad','1990','2001','ABC-100')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Chad','2002','2004','GHI-301')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Chad','1997','2003','GHI-300')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Brandon','1985','1995','JKL-400')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Brandon','1999','2009','JKL-401')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Brandon','1996','2002','JKL-400')
INTO ZZ_YEARRANGE (NAME,STARTYEAR,ENDYEAR,IDNUM) VALUES ('Brandon','2003','2007','JKL-400')
select 1 from DUAL;
```

The Table should look like this:

```
Derick  1995    1998    ABC-100
Derick  1999    2005    ABC-100
Derick  1998    2003    ABC-101
Rick    2001    2010    DEF-200
Rick    2007    2015    DEF-200
Rick    2002    2008    DEF-201
Chad    1990    2001    ABC-100
Chad    2002    2004    GHI-301
Chad    1997    2003    GHI-300
Brandon 1985    1995    JKL-400
Brandon 1999    2009    JKL-401
Brandon 1996    2002    JKL-400
Brandon 2003    2007    JKL-400
```

And the Results I am trying to get is:

```
Derick  1995    2005    ABC-100
Derick  1998    2003    ABC-101
Rick    2001    2015    DEF-200
Rick    2002    2008    DEF-201
Chad    1990    2001    ABC-100
Chad    2002    2004    GHI-301
Chad    1997    2003    GHI-300
Brandon 1985    2007    JKL-400
Brandon 1999    2009    JKL-401
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as you put the *distinct* columns in the `GROUP BY`and add `MIN` and `MAX` to other columns as required:

```
select NAME, min(STARTYEAR) STARTYEAR, max(ENDYEAR) ENDYEAR, IDNUM
from   ZZ_YEARRANGE
group by  NAME, IDNUM
order by NAME, IDNUM

NAME       STARTYEAR ENDYEAR IDNUM    
---------- --------- ------- ----------
Brandon    1985      2007    JKL-400    
Brandon    1999      2009    JKL-401    
Chad       1990      2001    ABC-100    
Chad       1997      2003    GHI-300    
Chad       2002      2004    GHI-301    
Derick     1995      2005    ABC-100    
Derick     1998      2003    ABC-101    
Rick       2001      2015    DEF-200    
Rick       2002      2008    DEF-201
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! For some reason I thought it would be much more difficult.